# Удаленный веб-сервер для вычислений

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine

Есть программа, написанная на Python3, выполняющая некоторые большие вычисления.
Всё выполнение занимает примерно сутки.

На своей машине я запустить не могу, потому что мне она нужна для работы.
Есть ли сервисы позволяющие удобно через облако выполнить такую программу и получить результат?

DigitalOcean или Google Compute Engine подойдут для этого?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можете еще посмотреть Microsoft Azure. Они себя иногда рекламируют в том числе и для задач научных расчетов.

Есть еще [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/ru/ec2/) (Amazon EC2). Вот цитата с их сайта:

> Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) – это веб-сервис, предоставляющий масштабируемые вычислительные ресурсы в облаке. Он упрощает процесс крупномасштабных вычислений в облаке для разработчиков.

Answer (score 2):

Есть сервис с предустановленным питоном
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/
Но я его не использовал, подробностей не могу сказать.